# Sending ajax response to another controller using Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a view from where I am sending a request to a Controller and as a result getting response back to the view page. Now I want to pass the ajax response in to the next Controller but I do not know what will be the type of response in Controller
This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<c:url value="/menu/menucheckout/${restaurant_menu.name}"/>",

                data : {"amount":amount, "orderoption" :orderoption, "date":date , "time":time ,'menuitemsArray': menuitemsArray ,'menuPriceArray': menuPriceArray , 'menuSpiceeArray': menuSpiceeArray , 'ItemQuantityArray': ItemQuantityArray },

                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);

                     window.location.href = "/BistroServicesMenuApp/welcome/getordercheckout/"+response.model;
                }

            });
```

Here is the Menu Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu")
public class MenuController {

@Autowired
private MenuTypeService menutypeService;

@RequestMapping(value="/menucheckout/{restaurantname}" ,method = RequestMethod.POST )
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView menucheckout(@PathVariable("restaurantname") String restaurantname , HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, NamingException, IOException
{

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/welcome/getordercheckout");

        System.out.println("COMING IN menucheckout CONTROLLER" + restaurantname);

        System.out.println("orderoption" + request.getParameter("orderoption"));
        String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
        String orderoption = request.getParameter("orderoption");
        String date = request.getParameter("date");
        String time = request.getParameter("time");
        String[]  menuitemsArray = request.getParameterValues("menuitemsArray[]");
        String[]  menuPriceArray = request.getParameterValues("menuPriceArray[]");
        String[]  menuSpiceeArray = request.getParameterValues("menuSpiceeArray[]");
        String[]  ItemQuantityArray = request.getParameterValues("ItemQuantityArray[]");

        model.addObject("restaurantname", restaurantname);
        model.addObject("amount", amount);
        model.addObject("orderoption", orderoption);
        model.addObject("date", date);
        model.addObject("time", time);
        model.addObject("menuitemsArray", menuitemsArray);
        model.addObject("menuPriceArray", menuPriceArray);
        model.addObject("menuSpiceeArray", menuSpiceeArray);
        model.addObject("ItemQuantityArray", ItemQuantityArray);

        return model;

  }

}
```

Now Here is the Second Controller "OrderController":

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping("/getordercheckout/{response}")
public ModelAndView getOrderCheckOut(@PathVariable("response") ModelAndView response)
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/getordercheckout");
    model.addObject("response" , response);
    System.out.println("Response : " +response);
    return model;
}
```

Now here I want to get the response but I am not sure what will be the datatype of reponse.

**The System.out.println prints this error:**

```
  ModelAndView: reference to view with name '[object Object]'; model is null
```

Please Help me out as I am new to the Spring MVC.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to know the type of the object ?

Comment: Then how I will pass the response on redirection?